# Can I use the ISP modem/router as only a modem? and LAN-to-WAN to another modem/router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem, dmz

My ISP forces us to use their modem/router. The provided modem/router is a custom NETGEAR VEGN2610 Telco gateway.

I want to manage my LAN, WiFi & QoS using my previous modem/router: a D-Link DVA-2800.

I can establish an internet connection from my ISP with the D-Link but they refuse to disclose SIP registration details, so I can't have VoIP for my home phone unless I stick to using the ISP modem/router.

I'm thinking of trying this set up... but I have questions -- particularly about NAT, DNS and Port Forwarding.

**on ISP modem/router:**

- WAN IP, Subnet & Gateway: *auto from ISP*
- ***DNS: Auto? 1.1.1.1?***
- ***NAT: Yes? No?***
- LAN IP: 192.168.0.1 (255.255.255.0)
- DHCP Start IP: 192.168.0.2
- Reserve: 192.168.0.2 for DLINK
- ***Port Forward: 443 & 80 to DLINK?*** *(for my WEB SERVER)*
- Disable: WiFi broadcast/radios

**on DLINK modem/router:**

- WAN IP: 192.168.0.2
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- ***DNS: Auto? 1.1.1.1?***
- ***NAT: Yes? No?***
- LAN IP: 192.168.1.1 (255.255.255.0)
- DHCP Start IP: 192.168.1.2
- Reserve: all my usual home devices.
- ***Port Forward: 443 & 80 to MEDIA SERVER?***
- Enable: WiFi broadcast/radios

**connect:** Ethernet cable from a ISP LAN port to the WAN port on DLINK.

***Would this work?***

Will double-NAT be an issue?
Should I just expose the DLINK to all ports by setting it as a DMZ server on the ISP modem/router? How is double-NAT not an issue then?
Where do I specify my preferred DNS servers?

The ISP's custom firmware version of the NETGEAR gateway is really restrictive, and the WiFi radios are not very good. I would very much like to manage the LAN and WLAN with the D-Link modem/router.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after trials and errors....

**on ISP modem/router:**

- WAN IP, Subnet & Gateway: auto from ISP
- DNS: 1.1.1.1/1.0.0.1
- NAT: Yes
- LAN IP: 192.168.0.1 (255.255.255.0)
- DHCP Start IP: 192.168.0.2
- Reserve: 192.168.0.2 for DLINK
- Port Forward: 443 & 80 to DLINK
- Disable: WiFi broadcast/radios

**on DLINK modem/router:**

- WAN IP: 192.168.0.2 (WAN type: Residential Gateway/Eth0/Static IP)
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- DNS: 192.168.0.1 (no secondary)
- NAT: Yes
- LAN IP: 192.168.1.1 (255.255.255.0)
- DHCP Start IP: 192.168.1.2
- Reserve: all my usual home devices.
- Port Forward: 443 & 80 to MEDIA SERVER.
- Enable: WiFi broadcast/radios

**connect**: Ethernet cable from a ISP LAN port to the WAN port on DLINK.

Hopefully this helps someone else trying to mash two modem/routers together without using DMZ/Bridge Mode/LAN-to-LAN.

Comment: thank you for your sharing!